# Windows Server 2008 R2 and Google Apps

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, domain, g-suite, google

Can i use the domain name e.g. 'contoso.org' registered with goDaddy as FQDN in Windows Server 2008 R2?

Comment: What does Google Apps have to do with your question?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you certainly can do this.